Переменная блочного кода, видимость снаружи без её уничтожения
В качестве примера возьмём следующий код:
int x=0;
{ // блочный код
 int y=0;
}

Допустим, что мы завершили выполнение блочного кода и вышли наружу.
Но представим, что блочный код всё также остаётся существовать, а вместе с ним и  переменная 'y'.
И теперь если мы попытаемся использовать переменную 'y' снаружи, что произойдёт?
Предусмотрен ли какой-то запрет на попытку использовать снаружи переменные, заключенные внутри блочного код?
Изначально это не удаётся сделать потому, что пока мы снаружи и до блочного кода, то переменная внутри него бывает ещё не объявлена, а когда мы снаружи и уже после блочного кода, то к этому моменту она бывает уничтожена. Поэтому и попросил представить ситуацию где блочный код продолжает существовать, когда мы вышли из него.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Автоматические переменные создаются на стеке. По выходу из блока указатель стека возвращается к значению, которое было до входа в блок, а переменные, объявленные в блоке, перестают быть доступны. Технически можно сохранить указатель на переменную внутри блока и использовать его после завершения блока:
int* py = NULL;
{
   int y = 42;
   py = &y;
}
// use *py

Но такое использование приводит к неопределённому поведению и потенциально неожиданным результатам.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int* py = NULL;
    {
        int y = 42;
        py = &y;
    } 

    printf("%d\n", *py);  // 42 или нет?
}

Например, без оптимизации имеем старое значение. А с оптимизацией уже видим 0.
Если нужно далее по коду обеспечить доступ к какой-то переменной, то следует или вовсе избавиться от блока, или копировать данные во внешнюю к блоку переменную, или использовать динамическое выделение памяти (см. malloc).

Если к py и y добавить volatile, то и с оптимизацией должно сработать, особенно если после printf еще что-нибудь вызвать. Но в целом, абсолютно верно, когда эта память будет переиспользована, заранее сказать очень сложно

Простите, но где здесь "попросил представить ситуацию где блочный код продолжает существовать, когда мы вышли из него"?

@Harry а разве наличие в выводе 42 это не оно?

@avp volatile по сути необходимую оптимизацию как раз и отключит.

@αλεχολυτ,   в какой-то мере отключит, вообще, volatile говорит компилятору, что при каждом обращении к переменной обязательно нужно обращаться к памяти (является ли такое обращение точкой синхронизации кода (т.е. запретом переставлять операторы текстуально расположенные до и после такой точки), не помню).

@αλεχολυτ, разве 42 даёт нам знать, что блочный код всё ещё активен?
Что, если без оптимизации значения ячеек попросту сохраняются после выхода?
Имею в виду, мы вышли из блочного кода, он завершился (уничтожился),
но при этом не стёр ячейки памяти в которых хранятся значения переменных,
и поэтому у нас сохранилось значение 42.

@αλεχολυτ, изначально обратил внимание на ваш ответ и ослепил себя тем, что кое-что новое для себя почерпнул. А сейчас перечитал, и вижу, что, кажись, вопрос всё также актуален. Только, думаю, будет ещё труднее сформулировать, что именно имею в виду.

Что такое вообще — существование блочного кода? Машинные коды никуда не пропадают в любом случае, остаются в памяти :) Но это же явное "не то"? Давайте до спора определимся с этим вот термином/понятием. Для меня это остается непонятным...

@Harry люди имеют разные уровни понимания (потому и задают вопросы) и используют разные термины и формулировки при описании своих мыслей. Моё видение вопроса (как я его понял) привело к публикации данного ответа, основанного на реальном поведение реального компилятора, а не какого-то гипотетического, где выход из блока оставляет доступ к переменным, объявленным в нём.

@NarelTojer, учтите, мы всегда видим только некоторые следы, оставленные уже исполненным кодом...

@Harry, в комментариях к вопросу переформулировал.

@avp, да, это само собой.
